# How to define a multi-parameter constant

Tags: macros

I am looking to define some technical requirements, and the reason why they are like that.

I would like to have something like:

```
\newcounter{techreq}
\newcommand{\techreq}{\refstepcounter{techreq}\arabic{techreq}}
\newreq{
label=apple;
nb=\techreq;
def={This is my first requirement};
reason={It is like because I said so};
}
```

And later, use it ideally, as:

```
This is my TR\req{apple}.nb, stating that \req{apple}.def, because \req{apple}.reason.
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Commands like \newcounter and \newlength assign registers by number to names.  There is no **req** register.  Use \newcommand{\req}{...} instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax has to be slightly different, because it's not really LaTeX adding a property name after a period.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % uncomment if using LaTeX with a version prior to 2020-10-01

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newreq}{mm}
 {
  \huberland_req_new:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\req}{mm}
 {
  \prop_item:cn { g_huberland_req_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }

\int_new:N \g_huberland_req_nb_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \huberland_req_new:nn
 {
  \prop_gclear_new:c { g_huberland_req_#1_prop }
  \prop_gset_from_keyval:cn { g_huberland_req_#1_prop } { #2 }
  \int_gincr:N \g_huberland_req_nb_int
  \prop_gput:cnx { g_huberland_req_#1_prop }
   { nb }
   { \int_to_arabic:n { \g_huberland_req_nb_int } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newreq{apple}{
  def={This is my first requirement},
  reason={It is like because I said so},
}

\begin{document}

This is my TR\req{apple}{nb}, stating that \req{apple}{def},
because \req{apple}{reason}.

\end{document}
```

The label is better set as a separate argument in `\newreq`. The second argument can then be any key-value list. The number is assigned automatically.

[image]

Actually, with a very recent LaTeX release (`L3 programming layer <2020-12-07>`) it is possible to have a syntax according to your preference.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % uncomment if using LaTeX with a version prior to 2020-10-01

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newreq}{mm}
 {
  \huberland_req_new:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\req}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__huberland_req_label_tl { #1 }
  \__huberland_req_get:w
 }

\int_new:N \g_huberland_req_nb_int
\tl_new:N \l__huberland_req_label_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \huberland_req_new:nn
 {
  \prop_gclear_new:c { g_huberland_req_#1_prop }
  \prop_gset_from_keyval:cn { g_huberland_req_#1_prop } { #2 }
  \int_gincr:N \g_huberland_req_nb_int
  \prop_gput:cnx { g_huberland_req_#1_prop }
   { nb }
   { \int_to_arabic:n { \g_huberland_req_nb_int } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__huberland_req_get:w
 {
  \peek_regex_replace_once:nn { \.([a-z]*) } { \c{__huberland_req_prop:n}\cB\{\1\cE\} }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__huberland_req_prop:n
 {
  \prop_item:cn { g_huberland_req_ \l__huberland_req_label_tl _prop } { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newreq{apple}{
  def={This is my first requirement},
  reason={It is like because I said so},
}

\begin{document}

This is my TR\req{apple}.nb stating that \req{apple}.def,
because \req{apple}.reason.

\end{document}
```

With this code only properties whose name consists of lowercase letters only is allowed, but it's not difficult to change the regular expression to permit other characters.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! 
It didn't work straight, but I reckon that I don't know at all what's behind, so I will have problem debugging it...

I will preferably go for a dirtier solution, as defining directly \newcommand{\appledef}{This is my first requirement}, since I better understand how it works...

Thanks anyway !!!

Answer (score 0):

Using [expl3's `\keyval_parse:NNn`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#page.199) and the [zref](https://ctan.org/pkg/zref)-package macros

```
\DefineMultiParameterConstant{⟨name of constant⟩}{%
  ⟨comma-separated ⟨parameter⟩=⟨value⟩-list⟩
}%
```

and

```
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{⟨name of constant⟩}{⟨parameter⟩}
```

can be defined.

(You can easily rename them to `\newreq` respective `\req`.)

The syntax of `\ReferNewMultiParameterConstant`/`\req` deviates from your specifications:
The name of the *⟨parameter⟩* is not separated by a dot but forms a non-optional undelimited second macro argument.

One approach could be using `\keyval_parse:NNn` for accumulating values of all parameters of a constant within a zref-property-list and then doing `\zref@labelbylist`:

```
\errorcontextlines=10000
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse, zref}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\zref@newlist{MultiParameterConstantPropertylist}
\NewDocumentCommand\DefineMultiParameterConstant{mm}{
  \@bsphack
  \group_begin:
  \keyval_parse:NNn \DefineMultiParameterConstant_SetProperty:n \DefineMultiParameterConstant_SetProperty:nn {#2}
  \zref@wrapper@immediate {
    \zref@labelbylist{#1}{MultiParameterConstantPropertylist}
  }
  \group_end:
  \@esphack
}
\NewDocumentCommand\ReferMultiParameterConstant{mm}{
  \zifrefundefined{#1}{\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}}{
    \zref@ifrefcontainsprop{#1}{MultiParameterConstant@#2}{
       \zref@ifpropundefined{MultiParameterConstant@#2}{\zref@newprop{MultiParameterConstant@#2}{}}{}
       \zref@extractdefault{#1}{MultiParameterConstant@#2}{
         \zref@refused{#1}\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}
       }
    }{
      \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
      \@latex@warning{
         Reference~‘#1’~on~page~\thepage \space does~not~have~property~‘#2’
      }
      \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}
    }
  }
}
\cs_new:Nn \DefineMultiParameterConstant_SetProperty:n { 
  \DefineMultiParameterConstant_SetProperty:nn {#1}{}
}
\cs_new:Nn \DefineMultiParameterConstant_SetProperty:nn {
   \zref@ifpropundefined{MultiParameterConstant@#1}{\zref@newprop{MultiParameterConstant@#1}{}}{}
   \zref@iflistcontainsprop{MultiParameterConstantPropertylist}{MultiParameterConstant@#1}{}{
     \zref@localaddprop{MultiParameterConstantPropertylist}{MultiParameterConstant@#1}
   }
   \zref@setcurrent{MultiParameterConstant@#1}{\unexpanded{#2}}
} 
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\parskip=\medskipamount
\parindent=0ex

\begin{document}

\def\SomeMacro{Definition of \texttt{\unexpanded{\string\SomeMacro}} current at the time of referencing MyFirstConstant before creating label.}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterA}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterA}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterB}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterB}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterC}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterC}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterD}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterD}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterE}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterE}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{foo}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{foo}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{bar}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{bar}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{baz}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{baz}

Some text.

\def\SomeMacro{Definition of \texttt{\unexpanded{\string\SomeMacro}} current at the time of creating reference to MyFirstConstant.}

\DefineMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{%
  ParameterA=This is the value of MyFirstConstant's parameter A,
  ParameterB=This is the value of MyFirstConstant's parameter B,
  ParameterC=\SomeMacro,              % \SomeMacro will be expanded while writing the label to .aux-file.
                                      % Thus referencing ParameterC yields "Right before creating label".
  ParameterD=\unexpanded{\SomeMacro}, % \SomeMacro will not be expanded while writing the label to .aux-file.
                                      % Thus referencing ParameterD yields "\SomeMacro".
                                      % What you get depends on the definition of \SomeMacro current at the time of referencing.
  ParameterE=\protect\SomeMacro,      % \SomeMacro will not be expanded while writing the label to .aux-file.
                                      % Thus referencing ParameterE yields "\protect\SomeMacro".
                                      % What you get depends both on the state of \protect and on the definition of
                                      % \SomeMacro current at the time of referencing.
}%

Some text.

\DefineMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{%
  foo=This is the value of MySecondConstant's parameter foo,
  bar=This is the value of MySecondConstant's parameter bar,
  baz=This is the value of MySecondConstant's parameter baz,
}%

\def\SomeMacro{Definition of \texttt{\unexpanded{\string\SomeMacro}} current at the time of referencing MyFirstConstant after creating label.}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterA}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterA}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterB}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterB}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterC}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterC}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterD}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterD}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterE}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterE}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{foo}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{foo}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{bar}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{bar}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{baz}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{baz}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Another approach could be having a single zref-label for each *⟨name of constant⟩*-*⟨parameter⟩*-pair:

```
\errorcontextlines=10000
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse, zref}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\zref@newprop{MultiParameterConstantValue}{}
\cs_new:Nn \DefineMultiParameterConstant_SetProperty:n { 
  \DefineMultiParameterConstant_SetProperty:nn {#1}{}
}
\cs_new:Nn \DefineMultiParameterConstant_SetProperty:nn {}
\NewDocumentCommand\DefineMultiParameterConstant{mm}{
  \@bsphack
  \group_begin:
  % !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  % If \keyval_parse:NNn would let you use "functions" which process more
  % than one/two arguments whereof only the last one/the last two were to
  % be passed by \keyval_parse:NNn, then there would not be the inefficient
  % need of (re)defining \DefineMultiParameterConstant_SetProperty:nn
  % again and again.
  % !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  \cs_set:Nn\DefineMultiParameterConstant_SetProperty:nn{
    \zref@wrapper@immediate {
      \zref@setcurrent{MultiParameterConstantValue}{\unexpanded{##2}}
      \zref@labelbyprops{MultiParameterConstant.#1.##1}{MultiParameterConstantValue}
    }
  }
  \keyval_parse:NNn \DefineMultiParameterConstant_SetProperty:n \DefineMultiParameterConstant_SetProperty:nn {#2}
  \group_end:
  \@esphack
}
\NewDocumentCommand\ReferMultiParameterConstant{mm}{
  \zifrefundefined{MultiParameterConstant.#1.#2}{\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}}{
    \zref@ifrefcontainsprop{MultiParameterConstant.#1.#2}{MultiParameterConstantValue}{
       \zref@extractdefault{MultiParameterConstant.#1.#2}{MultiParameterConstantValue}{
         \zref@refused{MultiParameterConstant.#1.#2}\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}
       }
    }{
      \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
      \@latex@warning{
         Reference~‘MultiParameterConstant.#1.#2’~on~page~\thepage \space seems~not~to~be~a~component~of~a~multi-parameter~constant
      }
      \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries??}
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\parskip=\medskipamount
\parindent=0ex

\begin{document}

\def\SomeMacro{Definition of \texttt{\unexpanded{\string\SomeMacro}} current at the time of referencing MyFirstConstant before creating label.}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterA}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterA}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterB}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterB}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterC}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterC}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterD}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterD}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterE}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterE}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{foo}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{foo}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{bar}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{bar}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{baz}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{baz}

Some text.

\def\SomeMacro{Definition of \texttt{\unexpanded{\string\SomeMacro}} current at the time of creating reference to MyFirstConstant.}

\DefineMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{%
  ParameterA=This is the value of MyFirstConstant's parameter A,
  ParameterB=This is the value of MyFirstConstant's parameter B,
  ParameterC=\SomeMacro,              % \SomeMacro will be expanded while writing the label to .aux-file.
                                      % Thus referencing ParameterC yields "Right before creating label".
  ParameterD=\unexpanded{\SomeMacro}, % \SomeMacro will not be expanded while writing the label to .aux-file.
                                      % Thus referencing ParameterD yields "\SomeMacro".
                                      % What you get depends on the definition of \SomeMacro current at the time of referencing.
  ParameterE=\protect\SomeMacro,      % \SomeMacro will not be expanded while writing the label to .aux-file.
                                      % Thus referencing ParameterE yields "\protect\SomeMacro".
                                      % What you get depends both on the state of \protect and on the definition of
                                      % \SomeMacro current at the time of referencing.
}%

Some text.

\DefineMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{%
  foo=This is the value of MySecondConstant's parameter foo,
  bar=This is the value of MySecondConstant's parameter bar,
  baz=This is the value of MySecondConstant's parameter baz,
}%

\def\SomeMacro{Definition of \texttt{\unexpanded{\string\SomeMacro}} current at the time of referencing MyFirstConstant after creating label.}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterA}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterA}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterB}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterB}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterC}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterC}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterD}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterD}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterE}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MyFirstConstant}{ParameterE}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{foo}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{foo}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{bar}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{bar}

\verb|\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{baz}|:\\
\ReferMultiParameterConstant{MySecondConstant}{baz}


\end{document}
```

[image]

(A noteworthy difference between the two approaches is that with the second approach providing a value for the same *⟨parameter⟩* more than once yields error-messages about multiply defined labels while with the first approach silently the last value provided is used.)